# Doing <= in Swift

Tags: swift, while-loop

I wanna make a while-loop with 2 informations.
The first: A variable should be smaller or the same as 500
The second: A variable should be 0

So here what I have done:

```
while fieldY > 0; fieldX <=501 {...}
```

And I get the errors: "Expected { after while condition" and "Braced block of statements is an unused closure"
I dont understand there errors because I have set all the { correct.

Than I thought the <= might not work so I tried this:

```
while fieldY > 0; fieldX 0...501 {...}
```

And the same errors have appeared. I have really no clue how I solve the problem.

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the 2 logical expressions are in `and`, then you have to do it as follows:

```
while fieldY > 0 && fieldX <= 501 { ... }
```

Suggested reading: [Logical Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_129)